# CMFCRibbonBar inside a CDialogEx

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog, ribbon

In my CDialogEx class, I am trying to insert a CMFCRibbonBar, but I get a NULL pointer exception (which is not caught by my try/catch blocks):

```
BOOL CmfcRibbonTestDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    // Set the icon for this dialog.  The framework does this automatically
    //  when the application's main window is not a dialog
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // Set big icon
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // Set small icon

    // TODO: Add extra initialization here
    try
    {
        m_wndRibbonBar.Create(this);
        m_wndRibbonBar.LoadFromResource(IDR_RIBBON1);
    }
    catch( std::exception& exc )
    {
        this->MessageBoxA(exc.what(), "Couldn't create ribbon");
    }

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}
```

The exact exception says: "Unhandled exception at 0x00d191db in mfcRibbonTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000" and breaks in afxribbonbar.cpp:964.

I did a number of searches to see if a CMFCRibbonBar can be placed in a dialog, but my searches were inconclusive.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at afxribbonbar.cpp, line 964 you will see this:

```
LRESULT CMFCRibbonBar::OnPostRecalcLayout(WPARAM,LPARAM)
{
    GetParentFrame()->RecalcLayout();
    return 0;
}
```

This should give you a hint at what the problem is: GetParentFrame() is returning NULL. By looking at the documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6f45sskz(v=vs.100).aspx we see: "The member function searches up the parent chain *until a CFrameWnd (or derived class) object is found*."

In your case, there isn't any CFrameWnd, so that's the problem. The bottom line is that ribbon bars aren't designed to be added to dialogs. That doesn't mean it's *impossible* to do, but at the very least it's going to be an involved process.

Comment: In my case this was a cross thread issue. In general MFC objects should not be used across threads, instead native win32 HWND handles should be used. I fixed it by using `AfxGetApp()` and getting main window handle from it. In my case main window and parent frame were same.

Comment: quote from wincore.cpp: `Note: if either of the above asserts fire and you are
writing a multithreaded application, it is likely that you have passed a C++ object from one thread to another and have used that object in a way that was not intended. (only simple inline wrapper functions should be used) In general, CWnd objects should be 
 assed by HWND from one thread to another.  The receiving thread can wrap the HWND with a CWnd object by using CWnd::FromHandle. It is dangerous to pass C++ objects from one thread to another, unless the objects are designed to be used in
such a manner.`